# How to adjust navigationbar title and edit the back button

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

[image: changes I want to make]

In the image i provided i want to do some minor changes using my viewcontroller. How do i adjust the word haffla so "h" is not blocked out and how do i remove the text "back" from the button!

Comment: Is the haffla text an image view or an attributed string?

Comment: the haffla text is the title of the navigationbar, so i guess it is an attributed string.

Comment: I changed the "h" to capital "H" and i am just gonna stick with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to remove the text from the back button from the navigation bar.

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```